# Using interface with contravariant type as a return type of a method in an interface with covariant type

Tags: c#, covariance

I need to create a factory which produces message builders and message senders. I've got three interfaces:

```
public interface IMessageFactory<out T> where T : GenericMessage
{
    IMessageBuilder<T> CreateBuilder();
    IMessageSender<T> CreateSender();
}

public interface IMessageBuilder<out T>
{
    T Build(EmailMessage message);
    T Build(EmailTask task);
}

public interface IMessageSender<in T>
{
    void Send(T message);
}
```

Problem is that IMessageFactory won't compile as compiler says that

```
Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'IMessageFactory<T>.CreateSender()'. 'T' is covariant.
```

If I make T covariant in IMessageSender, I cannot use it as a type of a method argument.

And I need T to be covariant in IMessageFactory in order to do something like:

```
    public IMessageFactory<GenericMessage> CreateMessageFactory(DispatchService dispatchService)
    {
        if (dispatchService == DispatchService.Service1)
        {
            return new Service1MessageFactory();
        }
        else if (dispatchService == DispatchService.Service2)
        {
            return new Service2MessageFactory();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

where

```
public class Service1MessageFactory : IMessageFactory<Message<Service1Message>>
{
}

public class Service2MessageFactory : IMessageFactory<Message<Service2Message>>
{
}

public class Message<T> : GenericMessage
{
    public T SpecificMessage { get; private set; }

    public string UserLogin { get; set; }

    public Message(T message, string userLogin)
    {
        SpecificMessage = message;
    }
}
```

I've reached a deadlock. Any ideas?

**UPD.**

Probably I'm doing everything wrong, so I'll just describe what I basically need, and maybe you can give me some hints about how can I achieve it.

So, I need:

1. to be able to create builders and senders for messages of different types
2. to have factories that will create builders and senders for each message type
3. to have factory method that will create factory according to a parameter passed to it

Comment: Why do you need `IMessageFactory` to be contravariant in `T`?

Comment: @BenReich I've updated my question to make it clear.

Comment: How about having interfaces for `MessageBuilderFactory<out T>` and `MessageSenderFactory<in T>`, and having an invariant `MessageHandlerFactory<T>` which inherits both?

Answer (score 4):

> Any ideas?

Make `IMessageFactory<T>` non-variant. Problem solved.

The system you've got right now is not type safe, which is why it is not legal. Do you see why it is not type safe?  Suppose you have an implementation of  `IMessageFactory<Tiger>` which has a method `CreateSender` that returns an `IMessageSender<Tiger>`. You can then call `Send(new Tiger())` and all is good.

If you can then convert the original `IMessageFactory<Tiger>` to `IMessageFactory<Animal>` -- because it is covariant -- then you can get an `IMessageSender<Animal>` out of it, and you can then call `Send(new Octopus())` but the underlying implementation remember *only takes tigers*.

The compiler knows that this can happen and therefore prevents you from compiling your program in the first place.

Comment: Maybe you can show me a way to do it right, considening the aims that I've added to my question? I've been trying to make this work for 3 hours already.

Comment: I can make IMessageFactory<T> non-variant, but then the question is - how to implement CreateMessageFactory() method.